# Is there a way to add onClick event to a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 kinds of buttons, a normal html button and another custom button. I can use onClick only on the normal button but the other isn't working.
The custom button I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import  './custom-button.styles.scss'

function CustomButton({children,isGoogleSignIn,...buttonProps}) {
    return (
        <button className={`${isGoogleSignIn? 'google-sign-in':''} custom-button`}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}

export default CustomButton
```

the code where I use it:

```
<button onClick={() => alert("Normal button")}>Click me</button>
<CustomButton onClick={() => alert("Custom button")}>Click me</CustomButton>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the rest of the `props` to the `button` and it'll have the `onClick` :

```
    <button className={`${isGoogleSignIn? 'google-sign-in':''} custom-button`} {...buttonProps}>
```

Comment: i wanted to know why this code i written isn't working, why the normal button is working and the other isn't

Comment: because the one inside `CustomButton` does not have `onClick`

Comment: aah i get it, you mean i can't use onClick on the custom component as it will be passed as props not like the normal button that will treat it as an event

Comment: yes `onClick` applies only to `html` elements, like the `button` , `CustomButton` is not an `html` element

Comment: how do we do this in typescript ? what is the props type ?

Answer (score 14):

`onClick` isn't firing on your `CustomButton` component because the underlying `<button>` element isn't getting the `onClick` handler provided to it. You need to pass the `buttonProps` on to the underlying `<button>` element in your custom button:

```
function CustomButton({className,...buttonProps}) {
    return (
        <button className={className} {...buttonProps}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}
```

The use of `{...buttonProps}` on the `<button>` element essentially passes all of the remaining props provided to the `CustomButton` component to the `<button>` element. So if you call the `CustomButton` with these props:

```
<CustomButton className="signin" onClick={handleClick} onChange={handleChange}>
  Click me
</CustomButton>
```

It will effectively render the button like this:

```
<button className="signin" onClick={handleClick} onChange={handleChange}>
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: i use this button in different locations so every button will have a different event so i wanted to add onClick on the component like the code i have there

Answer (score 0):

Define the props in the custom button element

```
import React from 'react'
import  './custom-button.styles.scss'

function CustomButton({children,isGoogleSignIn,...buttonProps}) {
    return (
        <button className={`${isGoogleSignIn? 'google-sign-in':''} custom-button`} onClick={onClick}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}

export default CustomButton
```

Edit: This will only work if you destructure onClick in the params (next to children)... Thanks for @Taki for pointing this out

Comment: this will only work if you destructure `onClick` in the params ( next to children )

Comment: Troy's answer above worked well for me. Gabriel's answer and Taki's comment are confusing. If passing {...buttonProps} to the custom component works (as in Troy's answer) what is the approach where you pass onClick={onClick} in Gabriel's answer? And what does it mean to destructure onClick and next to children? Has the code snippet been modified to reflect this comment?